# How to keep image style when material menu is opened

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material

I've added an popout animation to an image whenever the user hovers over the image. The image also has a custom context menu. The effect works as expected on hover but goes away as soon as the context menu is launched by right clicking the image. I need the effect to remain even when the context menu is launched. How can I do this? Thanks in advance for your help.

Template Code:

```
<image class="image" (contextmenu)="onContextMenu($event)" href="assets/images/USER.png" width="150" height="135" image-rendering="optimizeQuality" preserveAspectRatio="none" />
    
<div
  id="contextMenu"
  style="visibility: hidden; position: fixed"
  [style.left]="contextMenuPosition.x"
  [style.top]="contextMenuPosition.y"
  [matMenuTriggerFor]="contextMenu"
></div>

<mat-menu #contextMenu="matMenu">
  <ng-template matMenuContent let-item="item">
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="onContextMenuAction1(item)">Action 1</button>
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="onContextMenuAction2(item)">Action 2</button>
  </ng-template>
</mat-menu>
```

Css:

```
  .image {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
    transition: transform 0.2s ease-in;
  }

  .image:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
  }
```

TS:

```
  @ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger)
  contextMenu: MatMenuTrigger;

  contextMenuPosition = { x: '0px', y: '0px' };

  ngOnInit() {}

  onContextMenu(event: MouseEvent, item?: Item) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.contextMenuPosition.x = event.clientX + 'px';
    this.contextMenuPosition.y = event.clientY + 'px';
    this.contextMenu.menuData = { item: item };
    this.contextMenu.menu.focusFirstItem('mouse');
    this.contextMenu.openMenu();
  }

  onContextMenuAction1(item: Item) {
    alert(`Click on Action 1 for ${item.name}`);
  }

  onContextMenuAction2(item: Item) {
    alert(`Click on Action 2 for ${item.name}`);
  }
}

 export interface Item {
   id: number;
   name: string;
 }
```

Comment: You could try adding a class to the selected image, which has the same attributes as hover, when opening the context menu and remove it once the menu closes.

Comment: @Fussel that's what I did. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use [`<img>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) instead of `<image>`. `<image>` element [shouldn't be used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/image).

Play with the `menuClosed` and `menuOpened` events of the [mat-menu](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api)

When menu is opened, add a class with the same style to the image and remove this class when the menu is closed.

css

```
.image {
  transform: scale(1, 1);
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in;
}

.image:hover,
.image-clicked-hover {
  transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
}
```

ts

```
menuClosed($event) {
    console.log('Menu is closed');
    var imageHtmlElement = document.getElementById('image');
    imageHtmlElement.classList.remove('image-clicked-hover');
  }

menuOpened($event) {
    console.log('Menu is opened');
    var imageHtmlElement = document.getElementById('image');
    imageHtmlElement.classList.add('image-clicked-hover');
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-context-menu-cgw2cx?file=app/context-menu-example.html)